# use of undeclared identifier core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm using core data in Xcode 7 beta 6 and I just generated categories and managed object subclasses for each of my entities. The issue is that when I try to utilize the properties created from the attributes in my model, I get a "use of undeclared identifier" error. I was under the impression that I was supposed to put custom behavior in the managed object subclass that were generated, however I was not clear on how I could use the properties from the categories in the managed object subclass, so I placed the custom behavior in the categories as shown below. I feel like I'm merely missing an import statement, but I'm not sure. I understand I'm using beta software.

**Core Data Model:**
[image]

**Thought+CoreDataProperties.h:**

```
#import "Thought.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Thought (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *objectId;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) id recordId;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Collection *parentCollection;

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *placement;

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *extraText; // allows for extra description text to be set. Should be in smaller print than headline text and should only appear as an option in text != nil
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Photo *> *photos;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) id location; // place a CLLocation here

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) id tags; // place an NSArray here

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSDate *creationDate;

#pragma mark - Initializers

/*!
 @abstract this method converts a CKRecord into a Thought object
 @discussion parentCollection will still be nil after this method executes
 */
-(nullable instancetype) initWithRecord: (nonnull CKRecord *) record;

/*!
 @abstract this method converts a CKRecord into a Thought object. photos set is not populated
 */
-(nullable instancetype)initWithRecord: (nonnull CKRecord *) record collection: (nonnull Collection *) collection;

/*!
 @abstract Creates a new Thought object with generic recordId, objectId, placement, and photos array
 @discussion parentCollection will still be nil after this method executes
 */
-(nullable instancetype) init;

   … other methods

@end

@interface Thought (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPhotosObject:(Photo *)value;
- (void)removePhotosObject:(Photo *)value;
- (void)addPhotos:(NSSet<Photo *> *)values;
- (void)removePhotos:(NSSet<Photo *> *)values;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**Thought+CoreDataProperties.m:**

```
#import "Thought+CoreDataProperties.h"

@implementation Thought (CoreDataProperties)

@dynamic creationDate;
@dynamic extraText;
@dynamic location;
@dynamic objectId;
@dynamic placement;
@dynamic recordId;
@dynamic tags;
@dynamic text;
@dynamic parentCollection;
@dynamic photos;

-(nullable instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

       // THIS IS WHERE I GET MANY ERROR FOR USE OF UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER
        _objectId = [IdentifierCreator createId];

        _recordId = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:THOUGHT_RECORD_TYPE zoneID:[[CKRecordZone alloc] initWithZoneName:ZONE_NAME].zoneID].recordID;

        _photos = [NSArray new];

        _placement = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

        _creationDate = [NSDate date];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype) initWithRecord:(nonnull CKRecord *)record {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _objectId = [record objectForKey:OBJECT_ID_KEY];

        _recordId = [record recordID];

        _text = [record objectForKey:TEXT_KEY];
        _extraText = [record objectForKey:EXTRA_TEXT_KEY];
        _location = [record objectForKey:LOCATION_KEY];

        _photos = [NSSet new];

        _tags = [record objectForKey:TAGS_KEY];

        _placement = [record objectForKey:PLACEMENT_KEY];
        _creationDate = record.creationDate;
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype) initWithRecord:(CKRecord *)record collection:(Collection *)collection {
    self = [self initWithRecord:record];
    self.parentCollection = collection;
    return self;
}
```

**Thought.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Frameworks.h" // includes Frameworks I'm using and some string constants
#import "ForFundamentals.h" // includes mostly string constants
#import "Photo.h"
#import "Collection.h"

@class Collection, Photo;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Thought : NSManagedObject

// I think I should put method declarations here

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "Thought+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

**Thought.m:**

```
#import "Thought.h"
#import "Collection.h"
#import "Photo.h"

@implementation Thought

// I think I should put method implementations here

@end
```

Comment: Wrong way round - property definitions should be in the subclass interface/implementation files, methods should be in the category files.  The idea is that you can then use Xcode's "create NSManagedObject subclass" repeatedly as you refine your model, and it will create/overwrite the subclass definition files, without overwriting your method definitions which are in the category files.  Sorry... except that your methods are overriding NSManagedObject methods, and so also need to be in the subclass files.

Comment: @pbasdf thanks for such a quick answer! I think you're right, and that is the way I imagined it. However, when core data generated the category, they placed the properties in the category file, making me believe thats the new place properties should be placed.

Comment: So I regenerated the subclass and categories through Xcode 7 and I've tried to add a method into both, but it actually won't give me any code completion, making me think that there might be something wrong the generated classes Xcode creates. Normally, when I think it's a bug in Apple's code, I'm normally wrong. However, this is beta software.

Comment: Apologies, it hadn't occurred to me that Apple might have changed this in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclasses of `NSManagedObject` do their initialization in `awakeFromInsert` or `awakeFromFetch`. Don't override `init` or implement `initWith...`. You have to wait until the object is instantiated, and alive within an `NSManagedObjectContext`, before you can set its properties.

Don't assign collection instances to your ivars corresponding to Core Data relationships (i.e. `_photos`, `parentCollection`. Core Data will do that for you when you insert or fetch the object.

Instead of your `init` methods, rethink your approach. Write a method `insertInManagedObjectContext:withSKRecord`. That method calls `-insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Thought" inManagedObjectContext:foo`, which returns an instance of `Thought`. Now, with that istance, set the objecgtID, recordID, etc–but with your accessors, not by directly banging the instance variables.

Comment: You are absolutely right that I should create a wrapper method around creation through 'insertNewObjectForEntityName: inManagedObjectContext:'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because I'm changing these creation methods from init to insertInManagedObjectContext:withCKRecord: should the return type of this initialization method still be instancetype or Thought? And should this method be a class method (with the +)? I would think yes to both of these because I'm writing something like a factory method, no?

Comment: I would make it return a `Thought *`, but I don't have a good argument to support that choice. Probably doesn't matter because `Thought` seems unlikely to be subclassed. It should be a class method though. I notice that MOGenerator's similar factory methods return `id` (method name is `insertInManagedObjectContext:`).

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that although I can't use `_name = @"string"` syntax to set property values, I can use method syntax, like `[self setName: @"string"]`. This seems very strange to me. However, the method syntax does work in both the subclass and the category so I guess problem solved… for now.

**UPDATE**

I didn't understand @dynamic. This [post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/282043-dynamic-stupidity.html#282045) helped clear it up. I can't use `_propertyName` because the accessor methods are dynamically created by core data.

Comment: The underlying instance variable `_name` is not exposed on NSManagedObject subclasses. And you should be using accessor methods in almost all accesses, even for NSObject subclasses, anyway.

Comment: Interesting, why is that?

Comment: You've got the @dynamic part covered. As for accessors...think of them as the guards/sentinels of your instance variables. There will be times when you need to do something extra around a property read or write. If you always use accessors, those are now special cases that you don't have to think about anymore. Consistent use of accessors also enables KVO (key-value observation,